# replacing the google maps API parameters value by float variables

Tags: ios, google-maps

the google maps API require parameters like this :

```
NSString *urlString=@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=43.2923,5.45427&daddr=43.4697,5.65427";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

in that example i have gived directly values of longitude/latitude but when i try to it as variables like this :

```
     float latStation=topStation.sstationLatitude;
    float longStation=topStation.sstationLongitude;
NSString *urlString=@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=43.2923,5.45427&daddr=latStation,longStation";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

this doesn't work, how can i do please, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringWithFormat:` like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=43.2923,5.45427&daddr=%f,%f",latStation,longStation];
```

You might want to have a look at the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).

Comment: thx a lot, by the way since we speak about google maps, do you know what parameter to put in the url to ask google API for `turn by turn` feature ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/).